# What is the view of Sunni brethern about apointment of caliph?

Tags: sharia, sunni, history, shia-sunni

I know in Quran,
Allah has revealed that

> "And We made an appointment with Moses for thirty nights and perfected them by [the addition of] ten; so the term of his Lord was completed as forty nights. And Moses said to his brother Aaron, "Take my place among my people, do right [by them], and do not follow the way of the corrupter's."
>   Quran : Chapter 7: verse 142.

Since, Prophet Mosses (Pbuh) left the place for just 40 days. And even Prophet Mosses (pbuh) didn't left his people without a **Successor** for these 40 days.

I also remember a hadith whose reference is not in my mind which is like this

> "when prophet Muhammad (pbuhAhf) left for some battle, he left Ali (a) his successor for the people and all other matters."

I have a question that how is it possible that Prophet Muhammad (pbuhAhf) left this world without selecting his Successor.

*This question is for sunni muslim brethern.*
As we shia's have the proof that Prophet Muhammad (pbuhAhf) selected Ali (a) his successor at Ghadeer Khum.

Comment: Related: actually duplicate: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14573/who-has-the-authority-to-assign-successor-caliph-god-prophetpeoplesunni-v?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The most commonly accepted opinion among Sunni scholars is that a Caliph should be elected by ahl al-hall wa’l-‘aqd (The body that elects the caliph, made up of highly influential Muslims with good character). According to Al-Maawardi  (may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him) the members of this body (ahl al-hall wa’l-‘aqd) should have the following qualities:

> “There are three requirements regarding those eligible to make the
>   choice (of electing the caliph):
>
> 1. Being of good moral character, including all its requirements;
> 2. Possessing adequate knowledge by which one comprehends who has a right to the leadership of the Muslim state and the requirements that
>      must be met in the leader;
> 3. Being endowed with the insight and wisdom which will lead them to choose the person who is most fit for the Imamate and who is the most
>      upright and knowledgeable with respect to the management of the offices of administration.” [Al-Ahkaam As-Sultaaniyyah]

But there is no specific instructions regarding selecting the members of the Ahlul-Hall wal-‘Aqd in Sunni Islamic jurisprudence. This [fatawa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=284731) provides some insights regarding how to select those who would elect the Caliph:

> **Some scholars held that they should be chosen according to the
>   customs and traditions of the society provided that the requirements
>   of the Sharee‘ah are fulfilled.** Shaykh ‘Abd Ar-Rahmaan Al-Maydaani 
>   may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him wrote:
>
> “The qualities of those eligible to choose the Muslim caliph and hand
>   the leadership of the Muslim state to him differ according to the
>   social context and time. The criteria in choosing the members of this
>   body differ from time to time, from one environment to another, and
>   from one society to another.
>
> It is a matter susceptible to change according to developments and
>   changes in people's lives, how educated and civilized they are, and
>   the scope of their social contribution. Urban societies and villages
>   are susceptible to significant social change; accordingly the criteria
>   in choosing the members of the Ahlul-Hall wal-‘Aqd varies.
>
> Since it is left for Muslims to decide such a matter, **they are
>   entitled to set the mechanism and criteria for choosing the Ahlul-Hall
>   wal-‘Aqd through which the supreme Muslim leadership is established
>   and do whatever serves the best interest of Muslims …**
>
> This may be done by electing the elite of a given community to serve
>   as members of a regional and local body within their regions and then
>   by each country choosing the elite from among them (those regional and
>   local panels) and those elites from different parts of the Muslim land
>   forming the main Ahlul-Hall wal-‘Aqd body to choose the Muslim
>   caliph.” [Kawaashif Zuyoof fi Al-Mathaahib Al-Fikriyyah Al-Mu‘aasirah]

**In the present circumstances, Ahlul-Hall wal-‘Aqd members may be elected through a elective process in which ordinary citizens will vote to choose the candidates.**